# Delete a specific Column in VIM/gvim with out using Visual Block mode

Tags: vim

Sample Input File

```
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           Name     |   S1    |    S2
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           A        | -4.703  | -2.378  
|           B        | -3283.2 | -3204.5 
|           C        |  8779   |  7302   
|           D        |  22078  |  18018  
+--------------------+---------+---------
```

It is required to remove the S1 Column, i.e

Desired Output

```
+--------------------+---------
|           Name     |   S2    
+--------------------+---------
|           A        | -2.378    
|           B        | -3205.5  
|           C        |  7302      
|           D        |  18018    
+--------------------+---------
```

Can anyone help with this

thanks

Comment: Why not use visual block mode? This is exactly what that mode is for...

Comment: As iam tring to do this, as apart of vim script!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In command mode:

```
:%s/^\([[+|][^+|]\+\)[+|][^+|]\+/\1/
```

This uses vim's built-in sed-like search and replace command.  Here's the breakdown:

`%` - for the entire file

`s` - search for

`/^` - the start of line

`\([[+|][^+|]\+\)` -  followed by `+` or `|`, followed by any number (`\+`) of anything that is *not* `+` or `|`.  This will get the first column, which we want to keep, so put it in a capture group by surrounding it with `\(` and `\)`

`[+|][^+|]\+` - followed by `+` or `|`, followed by any number (`\+`) of anything that is *not* `+` or `|`.  This will get the second column, which we don't want to keep, so no capture group.

`/\1/` - replace everything we matched with the first capture group (which contains the first column).  This effectively replaces the first and second column with the contents of the first column.

Like I said, vim's regex are pretty much identical to sed, so you if you look through [this tutorial on sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) you'll probably pick up a lot of useful stuff for vim as well.

***Edit***

In response to the OP's request to make this more generally capable of deleting *any* column:

```
:%s/^\(\([[+|][^+|]\+\)\{1\}\)[+|][^+|]\+/\1/
```

The index inside of the `\{\}`, now deletes the column indicated.  Think of it like an array index (i.e. starts at zero).  So `\{0\}` now deletes the first column, `\{1\}` deletes the second, and so on.

Comment: So, Thanks :) Can you explain this a little Bit

Comment: Lol I just added a line to my answer asking you that very thing.  One second.

Comment: Awesome! Great Explaination!!

Comment: Like Wise Can you explain to remove S2 Column and letting S1 Column Present!! Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Consider simplifying that generic version to `%s/^\v([+|](.{-}[+|]){2}).{-}[+|]/\1/`. Although I _still_ prefer the /-+- regex in my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

## Look, ma: no *visual (block) mode* !

My pragmatic approach wins would be: look for column anchors (`-+-`)

```
/-+-
```

Now, the column deletion is as simple as

```
d<C-v>N
```

(delete, block-wise, to the next occurrence of the column anchor from the end of the document).

### Job done.

---

#### Fancy options

To account for multiple columns, you'd like to be precise about which column to match

This needs a little extra oomph

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>+</kbd></kbd>
  `:exec '/\%' . col('.') . 'v\v[+|]'`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
  <kbd>N</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
  <kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>+</kbd></kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

To see more about this `\%22v` way to select a virtual column, see

- [Support in vim for specific types of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400291/support-in-vim-for-specific-types-of-comments/10403779#10403779)

Comment: Brilliant. This answer deserves a +1

Comment: Hah. Thanks. I just edited my description to make it clear that I'm, in fact, not using visual block mode in the first part

Comment: To the individual who downvoted: would you like to explain what could be improved about this answer?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to write *Mathias Schwarz*'s comment into an answer because Visual Mode is the natural way for the task, although there is already an accepted answer.

Assuming cursor is in ¶

```
+--------------------+¶--------+---------
|           Name     |   S1    |    S2  
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           A        | -4.703  | -2.378  
|           B        | -3283.2 | -3204.5 
|           C        |  8779   |  7302   
|           D        |  22078  |  18018  
+--------------------+---------+---------
```

Use normal command <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>`8jf+d` to select `S1` column and delete it. Explanation:

- **<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>**: Enter in Blockwise Visual Mode.
- **8j**: Eigth is the number of rows of the table, it sets cursor at same column but last line.
- **f+**: Move cursor until next `+` character.
- **d**: delete visual selection.

And result is:

```
+--------------------+---------
|           Name     |    S2
+--------------------+---------
|           A        | -2.378  
|           B        | -3204.5 
|           C        |  7302   
|           D        |  18018  
+--------------------+---------
```

Comment: I have both simplified the approach _and_ provided a more precise way of addressing (instead of the arbitrary unit 8j) in **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519837/85371)**

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only content of the file, the simplest way is to use this:

```
:%normal 22|d32|
```

IF there is more text in the file, specifies the line interval:

```
:X,Ynormal 22|d32|
```

Where X and Y is the line interval, for example: `10,17normal 22|d32|`

If you're not familiar with the normal command and with the | "motion" there goes a quick explanation:

1. The `normal` command execute the following commands in the **normal** mode;
2. The | "motion" moves the cursor to a specified column, so `22|` moves the cursor to the 22nd column;

Basically what `:X,Ynormal 22|d32|`does is to move the cursor to the 22nd column (`22|`) and deletes everything (`d`) until the 32nd column (`32|`) for **every line** specified by X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Based on patterns of your table, this can be achieved in two simple commands:

```
:%norm 2f+dF+
:%norm 2f|dF|
```

Where `2` is your column to remove (`1` will remove 1st, `3` - 3rd).

This works as below (for each line at once):

1. **F**ind second corresponding character of the column (`2f+` or `2f|`).
2. **D**elete backwards to the next **f**ound character of the column (`dF+` or `dF|`).

Here is command line approach removing 2nd column in-place:

```
$ ex +'%norm 2f+dF+' +'%norm 2f|dF|' -scx cols2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like:

```
:%s/\%>21c.*\%<32c//g
```